# Vector of references to template functions

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, vector, reference

I have many functions defined like so :

```
template<class T>
std::tuple<Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>> gaussSeidel(Matrix<T> const& A, Matrix<T> const& b, long double precision) {
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to hold a reference to them all in a templated vector variable, that I try to declare like so :

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::tuple<Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>> (&) (Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>, T)> functs {gaussSeidel<T>, jacobi<T>, richardson<T>, sor<T>, gmres<T>};
```

It throws many C2528 errors at instanciation (`decltype(auto) functs<long double>`) when compiling in Visual Studio, emerging all from the allocator.  Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know you need a vector of pointers to functions not references to functions.
You should replace the (&) with (*)

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::tuple<Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>> (*)(Matrix<T> const&, Matrix<T> const&, long double)> functs {gaussSeidel<T>, jacobi<T>, richardson<T>, sor<T>, gmres<T>};
```

Comment: I tried this in the first place, but then I can't get the declaration to compile. The error is C2440, can't convert initializer list to `std::vector<...>`

Comment: You also need all the parameters to match. You have pass by value instead of pass by const& in your sample

Comment: Well, it worked. One of them wasn't defined exactly like the others (missing const reference) which triggered the error. You have to admit it's not exactly explicit ! Thanks for your help.